# mongodb always crashes with docker-compose file

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.1"
services: 
  mongo: 
    image: mongo:focal
    user: 1000:1000
    networks: 
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: "172.19.0.15"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME="root"
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD="mongo#123"
    command: mongod --verbose --dbpath=/data/db
    volumes:
    - /data/mongo:/data/db

  mongo-admin:
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    networks: 
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: "172.19.0.16"
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME="root"
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD="mongo#123"
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://root:mongo#123@mongo:27017/"


    
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.19.0.0/24"
          gateway: "172.19.0.1"
```

whenever I run it it errors out:

```
Attaching to environment_mongo-admin_1, environment_mongo_1
mongo-admin_1  | Waiting for mongo:27017...
mongo-admin_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
mongo-admin_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
mongo_1        | about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
mongo_1        | forked process: 20
mongo_1        | 
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.185+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.187+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.200+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.201+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.202+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.204+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.204+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.205+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.205+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22940,   "ctx":"main","msg":"file descriptor and connection resource limits","attr":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576,"conn":838860}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.206+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.207+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":20,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"e2237d5770b6"}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.207+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.8","gitVersion":"c87e1c23421bf79614baf500fda6622bd90f674e","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.207+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.208+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017,"tls":{"mode":"disabled"}},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/data/db"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/proc/1/fd/1","verbosity":1}}}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.212+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22940,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"file descriptor and connection resource limits","attr":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576,"conn":838860}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.214+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23104,   "ctx":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","msg":"Starting thread","attr":{"threadName":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","poolName":"OCSPManagerHTTP"}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.214+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":23074,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db","file":"src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp","line":214}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.215+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db"}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.215+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.216+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":23074,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"NotWritablePrimary: not primary so can't step down","file":"src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp","line":2589}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.216+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.216+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.217+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.217+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.219+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.219+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.220+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.222+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.224+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.224+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.224+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.225+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.225+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.225+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.226+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.226+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.226+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.227+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23105,   "ctx":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","msg":"Shutting down thread","attr":{"threadName":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","poolName":"OCSPManagerHTTP"}}
mongo_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-01T09:51:29.227+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
mongo_1        | ERROR: child process failed, exited with 100
mongo_1        | To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
environment_mongo_1 exited with code 100
mongo-admin_1  | Wed Jun  1 09:51:29 UTC 2022 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (2/5)
mongo-admin_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: mongo: Try again
mongo-admin_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-admin_1  | Wed Jun  1 09:51:35 UTC 2022 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (3/5)
mongo-admin_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: mongo: Try again
mongo-admin_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-admin_1  | Wed Jun  1 09:51:41 UTC 2022 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (4/5)
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

what is the issue in my docker-compose file for mongodb?

Comment: Error: ```"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db"}}```

Comment: tried this in the machine sudo chmod a+rwx /data/mongo same error. how to give it rights inside docker container?

Comment: /data must be writable too. What host OS are you using? Do you have SELinux enabled on the host system? Why do you need data on host machine at the first place?

Comment: ubuntu jellyfish